# Print image from imageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, printing, airprint

UIPrintInteractionController uses data to be printed.if I want to print image from imageview it gives me some warning.I want to use image from imageview not from resources.I want to know how to get data from image in ImageView

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
NSData  * datatobeprinted [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageView.image];
if(printController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:imageView.image]) {

    printController.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    printController.printInfo = printInfo;
    printController.showsPageRange = YES;
    [printController setPrintingItem:datatobeprinted];      
 }
```

Comment: You can get it like UIImage *image = imageView.image.But after this you want to use it where?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need NSData from image, then you can do as follows:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7); // 0.7 is JPG quality
```

or

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Depending if you want your data in PNG format or JPG format.